# Create a nodejs container Docker based on ubuntu

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, docker

I used the official nodejs image to create a docker container that run a nodejs app.

But now I want to create the same docker but my own base on ubuntu:14.04 but it doesn't work

Dockerfile mynode

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get upgrade -y

RUN apt-get install nodejs -y
RUN apt-get install nodejs-legacy -y
RUN apt-get install npm -y

RUN npm install -g nodemon

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY ./prj/package.json /usr/src/app/
RUN  npm install
ADD ./prj /usr/src/app

EXPOSE  9977

# Run app using nodemon
CMD ["nodemon", "/usr/src/app/app.js"]
```

If I change the line from ubuntu:14.04 to node it works well.

But now if I use a docker-compose to build and run the container it doesn't work.

```
node:
    restart: always
    build: ./mynodeFolder
    ports:
        - "9977:9977"
```

I have the error : 
[image]

Now if I use the image build with the mynode DockerFile and use `docker run -it --rm myNewContainer bash` and then start my app using nodemon it works perfectly !

So everything is well installed and packed within the my dockerimage, so why it doesn't work when build with the docker-compose

It works now when i use this DockerFile

```
# Set the base image to Ubuntu
FROM ubuntu:14.04

#FOR DEBUGGING  
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get upgrade -y

RUN apt-get install nodejs -y
RUN apt-get install nodejs-legacy -y
RUN apt-get install npm -y

# Install nodemon
RUN npm install -g nodemon

# Provides cached layer for node_modules
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app 

# Define working directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
ADD ./prj /usr/src/app
RUN npm install

# Expose port
EXPOSE  9977

# Run app using nodemon
CMD ["nodemon", "/usr/src/app/app.js"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the Dockerfile for the official `node` image:
https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/blob/5d433ece4d221fac7e38efbec25ffea2dea56286/5.2/Dockerfile

```
RUN set -ex && for key in 9554F04D7259F04124DE6B476D5A82AC7E37093B 94AE36675C464D64BAFA68DD7434390BDBE9B9C5 0034A06D9D9B0064CE8ADF6BF1747F4AD2306D93 FD3A5288F042B6850C66B31F09FE44734EB7990E 71DCFD284A79C3B38668286BC97EC7A07EDE3FC1 DD8F2338BAE7501E3DD5AC78C273792F7D83545D ; do gpg --keyserver ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys "$key"; done
ENV NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=info
ENV NODE_VERSION=5.2.0
RUN curl -SLO "https://nodejs.org/dist/v$NODE_VERSION/node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-x64.tar.gz" && curl -SLO "https://nodejs.org/dist/v$NODE_VERSION/SHASUMS256.txt.asc" && gpg --verify SHASUMS256.txt.asc && grep " node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-x64.tar.gz\$" SHASUMS256.txt.asc | sha256sum -c - && tar -xzf "node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-x64.tar.gz" -C /usr/local --strip-components=1 && rm "node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-x64.tar.gz" SHASUMS256.txt.asc
CMD "node"
```

If you go to http://imagelayers.io, you can see the combined Dockerfile for the image, including the `buildpack-deps:jessie` base image:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends ca-certificates curl wget && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends bzr git mercurial openssh-client subversion procps && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends autoconf automake bzip2 file g++ gcc imagemagick libbz2-dev libc6-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev libevent-dev libffi-dev libgeoip-dev libglib2.0-dev libjpeg-dev liblzma-dev libmagickcore-dev libmagickwand-dev libmysqlclient-dev libncurses-dev libpng-dev libpq-dev libreadline-dev libsqlite3-dev libssl-dev libtool libwebp-dev libxml2-dev libxslt-dev libyaml-dev make patch xz-utils zlib1g-dev && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN set -ex && for key in 9554F04D7259F04124DE6B476D5A82AC7E37093B 94AE36675C464D64BAFA68DD7434390BDBE9B9C5 0034A06D9D9B0064CE8ADF6BF1747F4AD2306D93 FD3A5288F042B6850C66B31F09FE44734EB7990E 71DCFD284A79C3B38668286BC97EC7A07EDE3FC1 DD8F2338BAE7501E3DD5AC78C273792F7D83545D ; do gpg --keyserver ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys "$key"; done
ENV NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=info
ENV NODE_VERSION=5.2.0
RUN curl -SLO "https://nodejs.org/dist/v$NODE_VERSION/node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-x64.tar.gz" && curl -SLO "https://nodejs.org/dist/v$NODE_VERSION/SHASUMS256.txt.asc" && gpg --verify SHASUMS256.txt.asc && grep " node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-x64.tar.gz\$" SHASUMS256.txt.asc | sha256sum -c - && tar -xzf "node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-x64.tar.gz" -C /usr/local --strip-components=1 && rm "node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-x64.tar.gz" SHASUMS256.txt.asc
CMD "node"
```

Comment: I see it but i was based on jessie and want it installed on ubuntu i finally get it worked